# "Weighted" random number generator

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm currently using the below code to grab a random element from an array. How would I go about changing the code so that it returns an element weighted on the percentage that I want it to come up? For example, I want the element at index 0 to come up 27.4% of the time, but the element at index 7 to come up only 5.9% of the time.

```
NSArray *quoteArray = @[    @"quote1",    @"quote2",    @"quote3",    @"quote4",    @"quote5",    @"quote6",    @"quote7",    @"quote8",    ];    

NSString *quoteString;

int r = arc4random() % [quoteArray count];
if(r<[rewardTypeArray count])
    quoteString = [quoteArray objectAtIndex:r];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an array of float (wrapped into NSNumber) objects.

Every object represents a percentage.In this case you would have an array of 8 objects:

> Object 1: @27.5 ;
>
> ...
>
> Object 7: @5.9 .

Then you get a random number from 1 to 100. If you want more precision you can also get a random number with the decimal part, and the precision doesn't influence the efficiency and neither the memory used.

Then when you get the number you iterate through all the array, keep track of the index and the percentage that you have. You use a float to sum all the percentages met and you stop only when the total percentage is greater on equal that the one that you have.

**Example**

```
NSArray* percentages= @[ @27.4 , ... , @5.9];
float randomNumber= arc4random_uniform(100) + (float)arc4random_uniform(101)/100;  
NSUInteger n=0;
float totalPercentage= 0.0;
for(NSUInteger i=0; i<percentages.count; i++)
{
    totalPercentage+= [ percentages[i] floatValue ];
    if( totalPercentage >= randomNumber)  // This case we don't care about
                                          // the comparison precision
    {
        break;
    }
    n++;
}
// Now n is index that you want
```

Comment: Note that you should never "%" a random number. It biases the result towards lower numbers in most cases. Use arc4random_uniform to pick a number in a range.

Comment: There's 1 case where this will crash: When you have only 1 object in your percentages array as n will increase to 1 when entering the for loop

Comment: I think the `n++` should be after the `break;` if case

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to generate a random number based on how fine-grained you want the percentage to be. To calculate to the tenth of a percent, you could generate between 0-1000, and 274 of the values you could randomly generate would be the first element. 59 values would correspond to element 7.

For example:

```
0-273    = index 1 27.4%
274-301  = index 2 2.7%
302-503  = index 3 20.1%
504-550  = index 4 4.6%
551-700  = index 5 14.9%
701-941  = index 6 24%
942-1000 = index 7 5.9%
```

The percentages don't add up properly, so I did my math wrong somewhere, but you get the point.

Comment: How would you set the first 274 values to equal the first element, 128 for the second element, and so on? My first guess is `if (r < 275) string = @"quote1" else if...` Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: What if he wants a more precise percentage? i think it consumes too much memory.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, that would be the easiest way, not really the most elegant. You can set it up with either an array, or use if/else logic. Using an array will take up more memory, but if you want a lot of flexibility with if/else, you'll write far too many lines of code for it to be really worth it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd use the 1000 (or maybe 1023) element array.  Even if the percentages don't work out exactly they'd be close enough.  And it can be a byte array (each element containing the index of the selected quote), so only 1KB or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another array with counter that would keep tracking how many times each one of your elements is being generated. If that counter is less than your target let that index come in your r, otherwise regenarate.